# office automation null reference exception (only on some installations)

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, office-automation

I've been using office automation for some time now, in order to merge data into a word document using the following code:

```
            oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            oWord.Visible = false;
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(
            ref oTemplate, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

I never had a problem with the code in the past, and all clients have the same set of referenced dlls (v12 of the office interop). However, a few days ago I noticed that some clients were sending out null object reference exceptions on the last line

```
oWord.Documents.Open
```

The exact same code and DLLs seem to work on some clients, but crash on others. Did anyone else have the same problem?

I tried uninstalling all the .NET versions on one of the problematic computers, and re-installing only the version I used originally (.NET 2.0SP1), but this didn't fix the problem. Could it be something to do with the office installation/updates on the problematic clients?

PS: I even tried installing the vstor (office automation visual studio assemblies) on the client with no success.

Comment: @ColeJohnson some optional references

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Well that is your problem most likely: missing is null and passing it when it is optional is just asking for trouble. It appears that the functions tries to dereference the null

Comment: The 'Open' method expects those parameters, it's not an issue of overloading... and besides, the code has been working (and still does on most clients).
Unless the office interop changed its implementation, and those client installations use the new dll from the GAC instead of the BIN?

Comment: They are optional. AKA not needed

Answer (score 0):

I've been through something similar, even installing VSTOR the error appeared ... The only way I could make it work on all machines was picking up the Interop dll's office and including the root of my project as "content" and marked for "copy aways". Moreover scored the "copy local" to false references. Try and make sure that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it! The other thing I was thinking of trying was to use the 2010 interop dlls on all client installations, which should fix the problem on the 2007+2010 office installations, but I don't know how this will affect the 2003 ones...

Comment: Watch out for one detail: The Interop dll's Office differ according to the version, incluisve impacting the references in the project. Example: If you implement the dll version in 2007, failed to run properly on a machine with a different version.